# How to execute a specific stored Job in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

How can i execute (better saying, trigger the job execution) of a specific Job in hangfire?

Comment: Does this have to be a in code solution or is clicking inside the hangfire dashboard acceptable?

Comment: I need to do it by code.